# Amazon Product Advertising API Reading reading first Offer

Tags: php, json, amazon-product-api

I use the [Amazon Product Advertising API PHP Class from Codediesel](http://www.codediesel.com/php/accessing-amazon-product-advertising-api-in-php/).

I use the function `getItemByAsin` and changed the `ResponseGroup` to `Offers` because I want to get the `IsEligibleForPrime` for the cheapest offer (see [Amazon JSON response](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Offers.html#RG_Offers-samrest).

Since there are more then 1 offer in the the response within the `offer` tag, I don't know how to read the first one.

Here is what a reponse looks like:

```
<Item>
  <ASIN>047061529X</ASIN>
<Offers>
    <TotalOffers>2</TotalOffers>
    <TotalOfferPages>1</TotalOfferPages>
    <MoreOffersUrl>http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/047061529X/?SubscriptionId=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE&ie=UTF8&tag=adrpik-20&creative=386001&camp=2025&linkCode=xm2 </MoreOffersUrl>
    <Offer>
      <OfferAttributes>
        <Condition>New</Condition>
      </OfferAttributes>
      <OfferListing>
        <OfferListingId>6vZH%2FR4dOoabV7sTSv3vC0Np5xK1c8MKOhAl5HYbCIJhxOLlJw1O2AM6mLYyVhjnI8s2gMkx7yq%2F%2BEC7yKPWkQTqhVhFBeUDm71EdpaYwrXpppfcAL1yPzyQFkOuK6MsK8aLPSNSWVs%3D </OfferListingId>
        <Price>
          <Amount>1025</Amount>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <FormattedPrice>$10.25</FormattedPrice>
        </Price>
        <AmountSaved>
          <Amount>974</Amount>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <FormattedPrice>$9.74</FormattedPrice>
        </AmountSaved>
        <PercentageSaved>49</PercentageSaved>
        <Availability>Usually ships in 1-2 business days</Availability>
        <AvailabilityAttributes>
          <AvailabilityType>now</AvailabilityType>
          <MinimumHours>24</MinimumHours>
          <MaximumHours>48</MaximumHours>
        </AvailabilityAttributes>
        <IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>0</IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>
        <IsEligibleForPrime>1</IsEligibleForPrime>
      </OfferListing>
    </Offer>
    <Offer>
  <OfferAttributes>
    <Condition>Used</Condition>
  </OfferAttributes>
  <OfferListing>
    <OfferListingId>uXUlLeu7rH5t3ogkZJ%2Bd11tWCsdsj5kHhjoscRF1D1GuBuDwCyrz0XyR%2BTEOJO7PgpfwLjtX4ojhbXeHZgM0Br4DiWsPhNZTduzvYC8zLgG0z1e%2FgYiiuuR0wTyKqssY6ncHyVjZK1A%3D </OfferListingId>
    <Price>
      <Amount>1110</Amount>
      <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      <FormattedPrice>$11.10</FormattedPrice>
    </Price>
    <AmountSaved>
      <Amount>889</Amount>
      <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      <FormattedPrice>$8.89</FormattedPrice>
    </AmountSaved>
    <PercentageSaved>44</PercentageSaved>
    <Availability>Usually ships in 1-2 business days</Availability>
    <AvailabilityAttributes>
      <AvailabilityType>now</AvailabilityType>
      <MinimumHours>24</MinimumHours>
      <MaximumHours>48</MaximumHours>
    </AvailabilityAttributes>
    <IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>0</IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>
    <IsEligibleForPrime>1</IsEligibleForPrime>
  </OfferListing>
</Offer>
</Offers>
```

How can I read the `IsEligibleForPrime` from the first `<Offer></Offer>`?

Comment: On which element you want to order ? The cheapest or the first offer ?

Comment: I would like to get the content of IsEligibleForPrime of the first (cheapest) offer where the condition is "new".

Comment: Ok, let's try something

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are working in namepace environment

First declare your namespace

```
namespace Amazon;
```

Second, instanciate your variables. Then, call the construct function of your class :

```
/**
 * Check from Amazon
 * @param string The ASIN we are looking for
 */
public function __construct($asin)
{
  $this->amazonAPI = new AmazonProductAPI(); // Or call from it right place
  $this->asin = $asin;
  $this->getResults();
}
```

And there, you call the function who is looking for the result you want :

```
private function getResults()
{
  // Call public function getItemByAsin($asin_code) from AmazonProductAPI class
  $items = $this->amazonAPI->getItemByAsin($this->asin);

  foreach ($items->Items->Item->Offers as $offer) {

      if ($offer->Offer->OfferAttributes->Condition == 'New') {
          $IsEligibleForPrime = $offer->Offer->OfferListing->IsEligibleForPrime;
      }
  }
  $this->eligible = $IsEligibleForPrime == 1 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

I have tested this code and it works for the ASIN you give in your question. Here is the result :

1. Is eligible

   ```
   Amazon {#17 ▼
     +asin: "047061529X"
     -amazonAPI: AmazonProductAPI {#16 ▼
       -public_key: "**********"
       -private_key: "**********"
       -associate_tag: "**********"
     }
     -eligible: 1
   }
   ```
2. Is not eligible

   ```
   Amazon {#17 ▼
     +asin: "B01E67UWX2"
     -amazonAPI: AmazonProductAPI {#16 ▶}
     -eligible: 0
   }
   ```

---

**Full source** :

```
namespace devSO\Amazon;

class Amazon
{
  /**
   * @var string
   */
  public $asin;

  /**
   * @var object
   */
  private $amazonAPI;

  /**
   * @var int
   */
  private $eligible;

    /**
     * Check from Amazon
     * @param string The ASIN we are looking for
     */
    public function __construct($asin)
    {
      $this->amazonAPI = new AmazonProductAPI(); // Or call from it right place
      $this->asin = $asin;
      $this->getResults();
    }

    private function getResults()
    {
      // Call public function getItemByAsin($asin_code) from AmazonProductAPI class
      $items = $this->amazonAPI->getItemByAsin($this->asin);

      foreach ($items->Items->Item->Offers as $offer) {

          if ($offer->Offer->OfferAttributes->Condition == 'New') {
              $IsEligibleForPrime = $offer->Offer->OfferListing->IsEligibleForPrime;
          }
      }
      $this->eligible = $IsEligibleForPrime == 1 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

And, indeed, you have to specify

```
"ResponseGroup" => "Medium,Offers"
```

in `getItemByAsin` function from `AmazonProductAPI` class

Comment: Thx for the quick reply, unfortunately `$IsEligibleForPrime` stays empty. I've tried to display `$items->Offers->TotalOffers` but even that is empty (for whatever reason). I've therefore check the `responseGroup` in the class but seems right since I use `"ResponseGroup" => "Medium,Offers"`. What am I making wrong?